# Unicode to text in java

Tags: android, unicode, textview

How can I convert a Unicode string like

```
"\u0646\u0627\u0645"
```

to a human-readable string that I can put in a `TextView`?

Comment: I edited your question to focus on what I think is the specific question you have. You may need to edit further if I've misinterpreted your intent.

Comment: ok never mind thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything more than this

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
text.setText("\u0646\u0627\u0645");
```

Comment: thanks that's worked!
but why it doesn't work when i copy & paste something like this from the json of my website?
\\u062f\\u0627\\u0646\\u0644\\u0648\\u062f \\u0622\\u0647\\u0646\\u06af \\u062c\\u062f\\u06cc\\u062f \\u0639\\u0644\\u06cc \\u0627\\u0635\\u062d\\u0627\\u0628\\u06cc \\u0634\\u0647\\u0631 \\u0628\\u0627\\u0631\\u0627\\u0646

Comment: That particular string is probably being read as "\\" with "u062f" which displays as "\u062f" which looks like unicode, but the "\" was escaped, not the "u"